# How to format edittext (android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to format an `EditText` to add a dot.

When the input is with more than 3 numbers put the dot after the first number (like this: 1.000)

but when the input have more than 4 numbers put the dot after the second number (like this: 10.000)

I already tried `addTextChangedListener` but it didn't work.

Comment: You should show us the code for your text watcher. I'm guessing you have something wrong with that.

Comment: Would you want 10.0000, or 100.000? Is it that the last 3 digits are after the `.`, or that with 5+ digits it should still be after the first two?

Comment: hi, i always want only 3 zeros after the dot.  1.000 10.000 100.000

Answer (score 0):

this algorithm is for add the numbers at the end and move the dot, like the next example:

you have at the begining 0.00
insert 1 and have 0.01
insert 5 and have 0.15
insert 9 and have 1.59

Try to modified that code and adapt it to what you need.

```
youtEditText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {
            boolean mEditing = false;

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(!mEditing) {
                    mEditing = true;
                    String digits = s.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat( "#,##0.00" );
                    try{
                        String formatted = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(digits)/100);
                        s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        s.clear();
                    }
                    mEditing = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

other thing is you need put the focus at the end of the text, you can do that with the next code:

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    amount.setSelection(amount.getText().length());
                }
            }
        });
```

I hope that can help you.

Comment: i try but doesn't work..  i always want only 3 zeros after the dot. 1.000 10.000 100.000    thanks